# Python: How to stop a variable from exceeding a value?

Tags: python

I know it sounds stupid and it's probably ridiculously easy but I just need a **direct, fast way of doing it** as I will probably need to use it throughout my code. 
I will paste my code here, also please ignore the fact that it goes on about Minecraft; I personally can't stand the game but it's somewhat of a running joke in my school. The actual code, though, is genuinely me just trying to practise ready for my GCSEs. Yes, I know it's not the greatest but I've only been learning python for a week. [Pastebin to my code: http://pastebin.com/QWtWJMvV](http://pastebin.com/QWtWJMvV)

This part of the code was my way of stopping my 'health' variable from exceeding 20: `if health < 20: health = 20`. Whether or not that is the most efficient way or if it even works is beyond me.

One last thing, it would be brilliant if anyone could show me an easier way of writing out:

```
healthRecover0 = (randint(1,10))
if health == 20:
    healthRecover0 = (randint(0,0))
elif healthRecover0 == 1:
    health + 1
elif healthRecover0 == 2:
    health + 2
elif healthRecover0 == 3:
    health + 3
elif healthRecover0 == 4:
    health + 4
elif healthRecover0 == 5:
    health + 5
elif healthRecover0 == 6:
    health + 6
elif healthRecover0 == 7:
    health + 7
elif healthRecover0 == 8:
    health + 8
elif healthRecover0 == 9:
    health + 9
elif healthRecover0 == 10:
    health + 10
```

because that is just ridiculous.

Comment: just `else: health += healthRecover`

Comment: Keep in mind that a mere `health + 6` will produce that number and then throw it away, leaving `health` unchanged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This part of the code was my way of stopping my 'health' variable from exceeding 20: `if health < 20: health = 20`. Whether or not that is the most efficient way or if it even works is beyond me.

You have this backward. You're checking if your health is *less* than 20, then setting it to 20. If you want to make sure it doesn't *exceed* 20, turn that alligator around:

```
if health > 20: health = 20
```

That is a perfectly cromulent way to write it, but you could also write it one of the following ways:

```
health = 20 if health > 20 else health
health = min(20, health)
```

As to your other question, you can replace most of your tower of `elif`s with `health += healthRecover0`.

Comment: You can even remove the healthRecover0 variable and just do health += randint(1,10)

Comment: Or `health = min(20, health+randint(1,10))`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, easy for me to understand too :) <3

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using

```
if health > 20: health = 20
```

is just fine (except for using `<` instead of `>`). As for the second part of your question, this should work:

```
healthRecover0 = randint(1,10)
if health < 20:
    health += healthRecover0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, really helped

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way is to use `@property` decorator. You can provide your logic fro checking max health in the setter:

```
class Monster(object):

    def __init__(self, initial_health=20, max_health=20):
        # Private property which stores the actual health
        self._health = initial_health
        self.max_health = 20

    @property
    def health(self):
        return self._health

    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        if value > self.max_health:
            value = self.max_health
        self._health = value
```

This way the value cannot be assigned a value greater than the max possible value:

```
a = Monster()

assert a == 20   # Intitial value is 20

a.health = 10
assert a == 10   # Changed to 10

a.health = 30
assert a == 20   # we set it to 30 but is capped to 20 max
```

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely help me to implement code such as this into it :)

Comment: If you found your solution please acccept one of the answers to close the question. thx!